# Sleep alternate in capybara? Can not pass the test without sleep

Tags: ruby, xpath, rspec, automation, capybara

I want to click a dropdown from the page and verify that it has certain things present on it after the click.

this is the html before click :

```
<div id="gradelevelDropdown" class="dropdown disable"></div>
```

and this is after the click:

```
<div id="gradelevelDropdown" class="dropdown disable open"></div>
```

my test passes if I use sleep for 2.0 after finding, but I dont have to use sleep as the client demands. What is the alternate?

Comment: Is the content of the div (the content you are trying to assert if present) loaded via AJAX?

Comment: I think it would help to share the test itself. Capybara should not need sleeps since it has built-in waiting logic. I guess the test is performing the assertion in such a way that the waiting logic is not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Are your finders actually working, or are they working only after adding sleep?

Your finder should probably look something like this:

```
expect(page).to have_css '#gradelevelDropdown.dropdown.disable.open'
```

That should succeed without having a sleep after it.